# Best style for dict initialization with optional parameters

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I want to do the following:

```
def func(name, par1=None, par2=None, par3=None, ...):
    pars = { 'name': name }
    if par1: pars['par1'] = par1
    if par2: pars['par2'] = par2
    if par3: pars['par3'] = par3
    ...
    do_something(pars)
```

This is too verbose. I could of course do:

```
def func(name, **kwargs):
    pars = { 'name': name }
    pars.update(**kwargs)
    do_something(pars)
```

But this is too obscure: I have no clue what parameters are allowed. The only way is to document them in the docstring, but even then that would not prevent passing a non-supported parameter. Protecting against this would make my function equally verbose.

Am I missing an obvious way of doing this robustly, explicitly *and* briefly?

Comment: What is it that is som "obscure" with the second example? I think it's quite stract forward - perhaps I would use the `dict` constructor on the first line (ie `pars = dict(name=name)`). Exactly what is it that you want from the solution? Without specifying this the question resorts to a mostly opinion based question.

Comment: @skyking: It is obscure because I have no clue, from the function implementation, about the supported parameters. If I pass an unsupported parameter to `func` it will just swallow it without complaining - which I do not want.

Comment: `allowed_args = set(('par1', 'par2', 'par3')); allowed_args.issuperset(kwargs)` Maybe make into decorator `@allowed_kwargs(...)`. Not too fast but probably nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) gives you something pretty concise:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import inspect

def args_dict():
    outer_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    info = inspect.getargvalues(outer_frame)
    return {
      k: info.locals[k] for k in info.args
      if info.locals[k] is not None # or modify for other falsey values
    }


def func(foo=None, bar=None, baz=None, qux='42'):
    args = args_dict()
    args['other'] = 'hello world'
    return args

print func(bar="BAR")
# prints: {'qux': '42', 'other': 'hello world', 'bar': 'BAR'}
```

You'll need to modify this if you want to take into account variable and keyword arguments, but the `ArgInfo` tuple you get from [`getargvalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargvalues) has the additional information.

Comment: Beat me too it ;-). I'd probably not accept the performance hit that one takes, though.

Answer (score 0):

What about filling the dict, then filtering out invalid values using a dict comprehension:

```
def func(name, par1=None, par2=None, par3=None, 
         par4=None, par5=None, par6=None, 
         ...):
    pars = {'par1': par1, 'par2': par2, 'par3': par3, 
            'par4': par4, 'par5': par5, 'par6': par6,
            ...}
    pars = {key, value for key, value in pars.items() if value}
    pars['name'] = name
    do_something(pars)
```

You can also go through and delete invalid elements from the dict:

```
def func(name, par1=None, par2=None, par3=None, 
         par4=None, par5=None, par6=None, 
         ...):
    pars = {'par1': par1, 'par2': par2, 'par3': par3, 
            'par4': par4, 'par5': par5, 'par6': par6,
            ...}
    for key, value in pars.items():
        if not value:
            del pars[key]
    pars['name'] = name
    do_something(pars)
```

It would be possible to put `name` in from the beginning, but it results in a more verbose test:

```
def func(name, par1=None, par2=None, par3=None, 
         par4=None, par5=None, par6=None, 
         ...):
    pars = {'name': name, 'par1': par1, 'par2': par2, 
            'par3': par3, 'par4': par4, 'par5': par5, 
            'par6': par6, ...}
    pars = {key, value for key, value in pars.items() if value or key == 'name'}
    do_something(pars)
```

or:

```
def func(name, par1=None, par2=None, par3=None, 
         par4=None, par5=None, par6=None, 
         ...):
    pars = {'name': name, 'par1': par1, 'par2': par2, 
            'par3': par3, 'par4': par4, 'par5': par5, 
            'par6': par6, ...}
    for key, value in pars.items():
        if not value and key != 'name':
            del pars[key]
    do_something(pars)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this, but the `pars` initialization line is too long, so it will have to be split into several lines (PEP8), making it equally verbose. In that case my first implementation looks nicer (and faster?).

Comment: You can split it into a few lines.  So, for example, have 3 parameters on the first line, 3 on the second, and so on.  I updated my examples accordingly.  But pep8 advises against one-line `if` tests like you have in your first example, so if you are following pep8 your first example would end up being at least twice as long.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a loss of elegant and fast ways, but a decorator-based approach makes it possible to at least hide the gory details:

```
from functools import wraps

def allowed_kwargs(*args):
    allowed = frozenset(args)
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for kwarg in kwargs:
                if kwarg not in allowed:
                    raise TypeError("{} got an unexpected keyword argument '{}'".format(func.func_name, kwarg))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Use as

```
@allowed_kwargs('foo')    
def test(**kwargs):    
    print kwargs    

test(bar=1)
```

This raises `TypeError` as the unwrapped function with explicit keyword arguments would.

You could also do something like this:

```
def collect_kwargs(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        forward_args = kwargs.copy()
        forward_args['kwargs_dict'] = kwargs
        return func(*args, **forward_args)
    return wrapper

    @collect_kwargs
    def func(par1=None, par2=None, ..., kwargs_dict=None):
        do_something(**kwargs_dict)
```

But I recommend against it. It seems even more obscure that simply not having explicit parameter names in the first place and it still clutters up your function signature. Or in my personal nomenclature, this is *decidedly evil* ;-).

Comment: That still doesn't help with the function signature issue, though.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Unfortunately, no. You could come up with a decorator wrapper that gathers up the keyword arguments and passes both kwargs and explicit kwargs dict. But that also makes your function signature unclean.